# How to use a Dutch tagger for a list with sentences in a list?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I've managed to find a nice Dutch NLTK tagger to tag POS in my text that I have to annotate.
My nested list looks like this:

```
['de', 'oude', 'tovenaar', 'overpeinsde', 'zijn', 'leven'],
 ['hij',
  'had',
  'spijt',
  'van',
  'de',
  'betoveringen',
  'die',
  'hij',
  'ooit',
  'gedaan',
  'had'],
 ['hij',
  'had',
  'ooit',
  'getracht',
  'een',
  'vredig',
  'rijk',
  'te',
  'stichten',
  'zonder',
  'oorlog',
  'en',
  'honger'],
```

and it has a total of 1096 words and 105 sentences.

The tagger I used:

```
 from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=False)
tagger.load('model.perc.dutch_tagger_small.pickle')
tagger.tag(wordlist[0])
```

to get the output of the first element.

```
[('hoofdstuk', 'nounsg'),
 ('ergens', 'adv'),
 ('in', 'prep'),
 ('een', 'det__art'),
 ('ver', 'adj'),
 ('koninkrijk', 'nounsg')]
```

Maybe it is because it is still pretty early, but I can't wrap my head around how to use this tagger for all the sentences.

Any hints, tips, guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a relation between `wordlist`, your sample list, and your output?

Comment: Can you post your full code or a minimal working example? Via indexation, you only tag wordlist[0], so basically your first sentence. I think this is the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have applied the tagger to the first element `wordlist[0]`.

Iterate all elements in a `for` loop and apply tagger to each.

```
for element in wordlist:
    tagger.tag(element)
```

Comment: No worries, if it solved your problem, please mark the answer as Accepted.